# redhat versus ubuntu linux distribution similarities?

Tags: server

I am being asked to use RHEL red hat instead of ubuntu. Are the basic commands the same? I know the licensing is different, but are the package mangers/repositories the same?
That is will 'sudo apt-get'   still be used? I have been using ubuntu for 4 years and have never used red hat so any information will help. Thank you :).
I apologize for the formatting of this post as I am on my blackberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As muru said too, basic commands for both distros are same but apt-get won't work as it uses yum.

imho apt-get is simplest when it comes to package managers, i personally like pacman more because of its speed, yum is bearable.

Also not all softwares available for ubuntu would be available for redhat, in case you want to use some software not available for red hat you will have to compile it from source to make it work.

If these thing don't bother you then go for redhat its a good distro and has its own ups and downs.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL/CentOS uses `rpm` for `dpkg`, `yum` (soon `dnf`) for `apt-get`. Packages are named differently, repositories are of course different.

Basic commands, of course, are the same, for a suitable definition of "basic".